# How to determine whether a user can login or not in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to find that a user can login or not in  MySQL without actually logging in.

for example:

```
mysql -u root
```

I do not need to login. just want to find that whether i can login or not?

any command options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the `mysqladmin` options such as `ping` or `status`.

For example:

```
mysqladmin -u root ping
```